# When I rotate the palm after automatic weight painting, the forearm skin seems to rotate and looks weird

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify, vertex-paint, vertex-weights

[image]

This image shows the arm before rotation.

[image]

Here its after rotation. 
How to correct it and is there any tutorial series for weight painting?

My .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Could you provide your .blend file to be able to help you?

Comment: OK, But how to attach it here?

Comment: using this link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3069" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3069/)

Comment: no difference in what u shared and what I gave